# How to share a link from the app using other applications

Tags: ios

I want to share a link from my app using other applications installed on my iPhone such as Gmail, Facebook, DropBox, WhatsApp etc. In android there is a straight way to do so, just fire an intent and it automatically shows the installed apps through which we can share whatever we want. Is there any such way in iPhone ?

Thanks!

Comment: how o? how to? Please correct the typo in title

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. You want a link that goes *from* your app *to* e.g. Facebook, or the other way around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the default iOS 6 share action sheet with available share options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498459/how-to-display-the-default-ios-6-share-action-sheet-with-available-share-options)

Comment: You cannot share stuff on watsapp because whatsapp does not have any public API you can use.

Answer (score 4):

On iOS , app is more separated from each other. The only way to pass data from one app to other is using the URL mechanism. As one example, an app register url scheme "open-me://",you invoked `openURL` with "open-me://my-link" then that app will launched. That app will define the detail of the URL so it could understand the content.Continue with the example we are using, the text you passed could be either "open-me://A?data=my-link" or "open-me://A?message=my-link". So there are no general solution for all apps.Typically third party app will provide a SDK to make these things easy.

If you don't mind using a kind of large third party library, [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) is a good choice. It supports quite some apps.

If you want to know more about this topic,for example sharing files between app. You could start from reading the class reference of `UIDocumentInteractionController`.This UI component will show a list of app installed on your device which support the URL scheme.