# Default Sharing in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, share, social-networking, airdrop

I have seen this format (Image shown below) of share option in most of the iOS applications that support iOS 7.
Is there a default code/framework available to implement this share option as it is shown in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-airdrop-programming-tutorial/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `UIActivityViewController`.

Since you asked a general question I can't do more than give you a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the accepted answer, a small piece of example code

```
- (void)shareText:(NSString *)text andImage:(UIImage *)image andUrl:(NSURL *)url
    {
        NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];
        if (text) {
            [sharingItems addObject:text];
        }
        if (image) {
            [sharingItems addObject:image];
        }
        if (url) {
            [sharingItems addObject:url];
        }
        UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
        [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Call `shareText`, leave the things that you don't want to share at `nil`.

```
[self shareText:@"Hello world" andImage:nil andUrl:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

The Controller in the image you posted is the UIActivitiyViewController [this is a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the class documentation

Answer (score 3):

some good example code:
[How to display the default iOS 6 share action sheet with available share options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498459/how-to-display-the-default-ios-6-share-action-sheet-with-available-share-options)

I know this question is particular to iOS 7, and the code example specifies iOS 6, but AFAICT they are very similar one might find the example code as helpful as I did.

Answer (score 1):

`UIActivityViewController` is what you are looking for.

You can specify either the items or the applications

```
UIActivityViewController *actCont = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use following code for **Default Sharing.** You can able to add more items into `shareItems` array as per your requirement.

```
NSMutableArray *shareItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
                                 @"Hello", 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"], 
                                 @"http://google.com/", nil];
[self shareItemToOtherApp:shareItems];
```

Following method is for default sharing Text or Image into other Apps:-

```
-(void)shareItemToOtherApp:(NSMutableArray *)shareItems{
    UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                 initWithActivityItems: shareItems applicationActivities :nil];

    [shareController setValue:@"Sharing" forKey:@"subject"];
    shareController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    shareController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
    {
        //NSLog(@" activityType: %@", activityType);
        //NSLog(@" completed: %i", completed);
    };

    [self presentViewController: shareController animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

If you want to make **Custom Sharing** sheet then use following code. For this, you have to import `<Social/Social.h>` framework.

```
-(void)shareOnFacebook:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *faceSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        // NSLog(@"%@", messageField.text);//This returns the appropriate string
        [faceSheet setInitialText:@"Hellooooooo"];
        //The facebook VC appears, but initial text is not set to messageField.text
        [self presentViewController:faceSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Please first install Application and login in Facebook");
    }
}

-(void)shareOnTwitter:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Hello"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Please first install Application and login in Twitter");
    }
}
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)