# How to share a MP3 that has to be downloaded from a URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a URL pointing to an MP3 file:
http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=Here%20is%20a%20test

I've been reading on some questions and I can't figure out how I can turn this URL into a file and then share that file using `UIActivityViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two different questions - how to download file, and how to use `UIActivityViewController`. The first can be answered with this: [How to download file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219848/4396258)

The second can be answered by taking a look at the delegate methods. Also this: [How to display the default iOS 6 share action sheet with available share options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498459/how-to-display-the-default-ios-6-share-action-sheet-with-available-share-options/13499204#13499204)